# Dynamodb Update Multiple Return Values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to make a Dynamodb Update return Old and New values?

something like:

```
updateItemSpec
    .withPrimaryKey("id", id)
    .withUpdateExpression(myUpdateExpression)
    .withNameMap(nameMap)
    .withValueMap(valueMap)
    .withReturnValues("UPDATED_NEW, UPDATED_OLD");
```

Answer (score 4):

There isn't.

It should be easy for you to simulate this by returning `UPDATED_OLD`.  You already have the new values as you set them in the update, so get the updated old values, and use that to extract your new values from your value map.

Comment: Thanks... But, actually I do not have the new value. because myUpdateExpression is something like "SET myValue = myValue + incrementValue". That's why I would like dynamo to return OLD and NEW values;

Comment: I see.  But in that case you still have what the value was before the update, and you will know what the increment is, so you can calculate the new value surely?

Comment: You're right I get the new value from Dynamo, then I calculate the old Value... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you want to use the data, if you don't need it in the body of code where you update a DynamoDB record, you can capture table activity using [DynamoDB streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html). You can configure an [AWS lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/dynamodb-dg.pdf#Streams.Lambda) on the table so it invokes the lambda when a specified event occurs, passing this event (in our case, the stream) to the lambda. From this, depending on how you have set up the stream, you can access the old and new versions of the record.